# How do I swarm Pikmin in Pikmin 3?

Tags: pikmin-3

In pikmin 1 and 2 you can "swarm" Pikmin in a given direction by moving the C stick around. I tried using the right stick and all the other buttons but I can't seem to get my Pikmin to swarm in Pikmin 3.

How can I swarm my pikmin? It was much handier than throwing pikmin when a large number were needed to attack a fence or carry loot.

Answer (score 3):

The swarm feature no longer exists as it did in 1 and 2, but a new feature is somewhat similar; when aiming at a target (be it an enemy, a collectable or a fence) you can press the Dismiss button and your pikmin will rush toward the target and perform their standard actual as if you had thrown/dismissed them onto the target (breaking it, carrying it, whatever). For this to work the creature/object has to be highlighted as if you could lock on/scan it, but you do NOT have to be locked on (you can lock on if you want though).

It's not quite the same as the swarm in Pikmin 1&2 but it will save you the trouble of walking over to a target before pressing the dismiss button.